# How can i repaint a composite in Java (SWT)?

Tags: java, swt, paint, composite

When i press a button in my swt program, a new composite should be drawn. But the composite only displays if i resize the window.
I have a composite (`compLoad`) in my gui which is assigned a new composite

```
compHELP comHelp_ = new compHELP(compLoad, SWT.RESIZE);
```

i have tried `redraw()` but nothing happens

Comment: What's `compHELP`? It's not part of the SWT API. Do you extend `Composite`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The composite needs to be re-layouted when adding/removing controls**, see

```
Composite.layout() // uses Composite.layout(true)
Composite.layout(boolean changed) 
Composite.layout(boolean changed, boolean all)
```

Note that layouts in SWT may *cache* the preferred size of its controls (determined by `Control.computeSize(int w, int h)`). As you are adding new components, a call to `layout()` might be sufficient. In cases where the preferred size is likely to have been changed, or the change happens in a sub-composite, use the method with the `changed/all` flags to make sure your layout is properly updated.

Side note: when the size of a `Composite` is changed, it will be automatically re-layouted (as you noticed when resizing the window).

Comment: thank you! it repaints with Composite.layout(boolean changed, boolean all)